# trac and subversion

Tags: svn, integration, trac

What kind of integration does trac have with subversion repositories?

Is it simply being able to view the source files or is there more to it?

Answer (score 6):

You can also place links to Subversion revision numbers in the tickets and wikis.  When viewing a revision in Trac, it shows you a pretty view showing the files that changed as well as diffs.  For our Subversion repository, we also have a post-commit hook that places comments in our tickets with the comments of the commits as well as a link to these revisions.  That is pretty convenient for doing code reviews.

Comment: That's a pretty good overview of features.  The integration is basically everything I could think of wanting from version control / bug tracker system integration.

Answer (score 1):

Be aware that Trac won't even let you browse your repository if it happens to be on a **remote server/share/location**!

This is **very limiting** in many cases where you want your trac/subversion web server to be separate from the storage of your repository (on a NAS for example).

Here is the Trac ticket related to the issue if you need to know more : [Ticket 493](http://trac.edgewall.org/ticket/493)
It's been open for some time now, and is the main reason why I'm going to move to Redmine.

Answer (score 0):

I found it easier to work with my subversion client.  We use TortoiseSVN and I wrote my own integrated client.  See this link [Here](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/issuetrackers.html)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the ability to add the commit comment in the tickets, we have a post-commit hook that ensures we reference an open ticket in the comment--if not the commit fails.

Comment: Technically, the Trac pre-commit hook rejects a checkin that doesn't reference an open ticket. The Trac post-commit hook inserts the log message as a comment in a ticket.

Its a subtle, but important distinction. A post-commit hook cannot reject a checkin since it runs "post-commit".